# Java Ordering a map or list

Tags: java, list, sorting, dictionary, hashmap

if you have a map or list with a bunch of doubles between -1 and 1 you can order them from -1 to 1.
how ever it is perfect e.g ( 0.4 is after 0.3 but before 0.5 )

is it possible to simulate putting the numbers generally in the correct place but not perfect?
its hard to explain what I mean but I have drawn a diagram to help.

The x's are points on the number line
[image: The x's are points on the number line]

I don't want it to be perfectly sorted, neither randomly sorted but in-between; roughly sorted.
is this possible if so how?

Comment: Until you manage to define exactly what you mean by `roughly sorted` I would say that it is impossible.

Comment: do you want to retain the order in which input is given ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914129/which-sorting-algorithms-give-near-approximate-sort-sooner

Comment: Sounds like you want to have them ordered but then mess them up a little afterwards, Think of it as 2 steps. order them then take random number of adjacent values and swap them.

Comment: @Keppil thats the problem there is no definition for roughly sorted. Think of it like whats 5/12? you know that 5/10 is 5 so its go to be less than 5 you can approximate it to be about 0.4 ish. that's what i mean by roughly.

Comment: Or you could sort them by "bucket", say, [-1;0], ]0;0.3], ]0.3;1] for your example. Your algo then only places the numbers in the right bucket but does not sort within a given bucket.

Comment: @assylais all the items need to be included, but i guess you could put all the "unbucketed" items sort them correctly in a separate map and then combine the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `TreeMap` (constructor with Comparator-arg) or `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)` with a `Comparator` based on `Double.compare(double, double)`.

This is correct for perfect sorting. About "roughly sorted", you have to write your own Comparator-logic. And please define your term how you really want to sort.

Comment: Ill explain what its for maybe that will help: The program is given a list of random words which are given a positive/negative rating to which one would be most suited. Then it is sorted and the top pos/neg word is selected, however I don't want it to return the perfect word every time, nor a random one but a better than average one.

Comment: In the link @assylais gave it has the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_sort I might use that and stop it after X cycles with what you provided to accomplish it. It was a theoretical idea I just wanted to see if this part is possible and how.

Comment: @user2871826 Maybe you can apply some kind of randomized multiplication on the real ratings and then sort these fuzzy ratings. For example: `Math.max(0.0, Math.min(1.0, x + Math.random() * 0.1 - 0.05))`

Comment: Fuzzy logic! why didn't I think of that before :\ I'm just going to play around and see what works better.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined 'roughly sorted', but one option is "binning".  Split the interval into *n* bins of width *intervalsize/n*.  Store the bins in an array or list, and each bin is a list of values.  Iterate once over the input set and distribute the values to their appropriate bins, which is *O(n)*.  You can improve the sorting by increasing the number of bins.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort them first, and then run a set random swap of direct neighbours. For example, with a list size of n, you swap n times at random positions.